# my dad uh has all that information

Tags: meaning

my dad uh has all that information

My dad, uh, has all that information.

My dad uh, has all that information.

My dad, uh has all that information.

which one?

Answer (score 0):

Since "uh" can be omitted without changing the meaning of the sentence, you should set it off with commas:

> My dad, uh, has all that information.

See:
https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/punctuation/commas/commas_with_nonessential_elements.html